# Проводник завершает процесс

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь открыть проводник в программе, но столкнулся с проблемой - папка при открытии сама завершает работу, и поэтому выдаёт исключение. Вот сам код:

```
CurrentDir = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Desktop\";
        try
        {
            Topmost = false;

            var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("explorer",CurrentDir + (sender as Button).ToolTip);



            //Здесь может понадобиться ожидание 
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            if (proc.WaitForInputIdle(Convert.ToInt32(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).TotalMilliseconds)))
            {
                //Здесь тоже может понадобиться ожидание 
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                proc.Exited += Proc_Exited;
                IntPtr handle = new WindowInteropHelper(this).Handle;
                SetParent(proc.MainWindowHandle, handle);
                Topmost = true;

                Button button = new Button();
                button.Height = 66;
                button.Width = 99;

                int i = Wrap1.Children.Count;

                Wrap1.Children.Add(button);

                (Wrap1.Children[i] as Button).Style = this.FindResource("GlassButton") as Style;
                (Wrap1.Children[i] as Button).ToolTip = (sender as Button).ToolTip;


                BitmapImage bit = new BitmapImage();
                bit.BeginInit();
                Uri u = new Uri(@"workspace\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension((sender as Button).ToolTip.ToString()) + ".jpg", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                bit.UriSource = u;
                bit.EndInit();
                ImageBrush image = new ImageBrush();
                image.ImageSource = bit;

                (Wrap1.Children[i] as Button).Background = image;
            }



           

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            
        }
```

Comment: `и поэтому выдаёт исключение` какое?

Comment: Процесс завершил работу, поэтому затребованная информация недоступна

Comment: какая конаретно команда тут строится `"explorer",CurrentDir + (sender as Button).ToolTip`? Вы запускали её вручную?

Comment: Там путь к папке. Прописывал и вручную, и просто explorer

Comment: `Process.Start("explorer", Path.Combine(CurrentDir, (sender as Button).ToolTip.Content.ToString()))`

Comment: Спасибо, исключения нет. Но возникли другие вопросы. Программа должна присоединять к себе на окно другую программу, с .exe файлами у меня всё хорошо, они цепляются, а вот проводник - нет. Второй вопрос заключается в том, как адекватно привязать проводник к событию Proc_Exited? С теми-же .exe всё работает нормально, а вот с проводником нет. У меня в данном событии стоит MessageBox (чтобы я видел когда оно срабатывает), и оно срабатывает сразу-же после открытия проводника. Как это исправить?

Comment: Другие вопросы надо задавать отдельно.